# Изменение состояние кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В `View` находится кнопка "Сохранить", выключенная изначально.

[image: View]

Нужно, чтобы кнопка включалась при изменении хотя бы одного из полей (Код устройства, Прошивка или Описание).

Для реализации INPC использую PropertyChanged от Fody, добавляю в `Model` свойство IsChanged. Как я понял, атрибут `[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]` самостоятельно реализует это свойство, но не так, как мне нужно, кнопка включается при выборе элемента из списка, что, в принципе, логично, так как поле меняется.

Пробовал изменить название переменной, но ума не приложу где проверять изменения значения в поле.

Разметка для этой кнопки выглядит так:

```
   <Button Width="100" Height="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}" Content="Сохранить">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDevice.IsChang}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Как можно реализовать проверку на изменение поля и изменения состояния кнопки, не нарушая паттерна MVVM?

Comment: у вас есть команда `ChangeCommand`, у команды есть метод `CanExecute` и событие `CanExecuteChanged` - вот их вам надо использовать

Comment: сохраняйте напрямую, без кнопки, самый удобный вариант, имхо.

Comment: @tym32167 Не понял, команда же срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку, или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Отправил ответом.

Comment: "Для реализации INPC использую PropertyChanged от Fody, добавляю в Model свойство IsChanged" вы уверены что в Model, а не в VM?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Уверен

Comment: не хочу вступать в споры, но таким свойствам (обычно) не место в модели.

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать редактирование с подтверждением, то удобно использовать диалоговое окно

Comment: или добавить в свойству `IsChanged` еще и `IsValid` для проверки не только изменений, но и допустимых изменений

Answer (score 2):

Я не претендую на каноничность, просто хочу показать общую идею

Итак, например у нас есть viewmodel. Тут 1 поле и 1 команда, ничего сложного.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _someText;
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _someText; }
        set
        {
            _someText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new SaveDataCommand(this);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Далее, команда

```
public class SaveDataCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly MyViewModel _model;

    public SaveDataCommand(MyViewModel model)
    {
        _model = model;

        _model.PropertyChanged += _model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void _model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_model.SomeText);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // execute something
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Как видно, команда вызывет `OnCanExecuteChanged` если меняется модель. Это заставляет кнопку, куда команда биндится, обновлять своё состояние запрашивая `CanExecute` у команды. То есть если в модели что то поменялось, то кнопка перезапросит состояние у команды - можно ли ей выполняться.

Ну, и, xaml

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Save Changes" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: не нравится мне такой подход. У команды есть `CanExecute` вот его и надо использовать, а не писать отдельную команду для каждой VM

Comment: @FoggyFinder так я просто принцип показал, ессно в реальном проекте надо использовать тот функционал, что доступен из местных фреймворков

Comment: @FoggyFinder ну так и использован же CanExecute команды? И он тут строго кастомный как раз потому, что доступность меняется в зависимости от свойств VM.

Comment: @Monk правильно, строго кастомный -> сильно связанный. Лучше написать: `new RelayCommand(_ => Console.WriteLine("Save"), _ => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeText));`

Comment: @FoggyFinder вы потеряли сигнал об изменениях. Команда не знает, когда модель меняется, её надо об этом уведомить, ну или снаружи как то сообщить ей, что пора перевалидировать CanExecute.

Comment: @FoggyFinder сорри, я не понял, вашу идею. Что с чем сильно связано? И как эта связь влияет на демонстрацию работы CanExecute?

Comment: `SaveDataCommand` и `MyViewModel`. На демонстрацию никак не влияет - я поэтому и не ответил на предыдущий ваш комментарий так как с ним согласен

Comment: @Monk не уверен что понял ваш комментарий. Второй параметр и есть `CanExecute`. Если я правильно понял вопрос то нужно не отслеживать изменение в модели, а просто обработать ввод пользователя как в ответе на примере с `SomeText`

Comment: @FoggyFinder а, ну я изначально хотел сделать `SaveDataCommand` вообще вложенным классом, потому да, меня их связь вообще не беспокоит :)

Comment: @FoggyFinder в примере есть `_model_PropertyChanged`, который помогает делать это "на ходу". Есть ли такая возможность у `RelayCommand` - я не помню вот так сразу.

Comment: Хм, а почему не просто завести свойство IsChanged и при любом событии PropertyChanged устанавливать его в true? Ну или написать простую реализацию команды с булевым свойством IsOn (в его сеттере вызывать OnCanExecuteChanged) и реализацией метода `CanExecute(object parameter) => IsOn;` и в подписчике PropertyChanged просто включать команду `command.IsOn = true` (ну или вместо свойства завести 2 метода `On()` и `Off()`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP а в чем профит от каких то дополнительных полей/методов? Я хочу при изменении модели обновлять состояние подписчиков команды - я именно это и делаю в коде. Не вижу смысла делать это как то по другому или что то добавлять в код, чтобы по сути сделать то же самое.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал такую простую команду-переключатель (ее потом можно использовать в других местах при необходимости):

```
public class ToggleCommnad : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public ToggleCommnad(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => IsOn;

    bool isOn = false;
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get => isOn;
        set { isOn = value; CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
    }
}
```

Это простая команда, имеющая устойчивые состояния "Вкл" и "Выкл", которыми можно управлять.

Тогда в нашей VM мы просто подпишемся на событие `PropertyChanged` и включим команду. Ну и для оптимизаторов можно потом даже отписаться от события, чтобы лишний раз не "щелкать" уже включенную команду:

```
class MyDataVm : Vm
{
    string myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => myProperty;
        set => Set(ref myProperty, value, nameof(MyProperty));
    }

    public ToggleCommnad SaveCommang { get; }

    public MyDataVm()
    {
        SaveCommang = new ToggleCommnad(_ => Save());
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveCommang.IsOn = true;
        PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    void Save()
    {
        // Здесь логика сохранения
    }
}
```

---

Если вы не хотите создавать новый тип команд, можно обойтись универсальной `DelegateCommand` (или как она там у вас называется):

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    protected readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, _ => true) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Но тогда флаг, сигнализирующий об изменениях, придется завести внутри VM:

```
class MyDataVm: Vm
{
    string myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => myProperty;
        set => Set(ref myProperty, value, nameof(MyProperty));
    }

    bool isChanged;
    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get => isChanged;
        set => Set(ref isChanged, value, nameof(IsChanged));
    }

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommnad { get; }

    public MyDataVm()
    {
        SaveCommnad = new DelegateCommand(_ => Save(), _ => IsChanged);
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(IsChanged)) return;
        IsChanged = true;
        SaveCommnad.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    void Save()
    {
        // Сохранение
    }
}
```