# Изменить доступность компонентов при старте процесса

Tags: c#, wpf

Изучаю WPF и хотелось бы знать, правильно ли я реализовал это или можно сделать было красивее.

В общем, в вьюхе у меня

```
public bool IsProcessing { get; set; }
```

Состояние которого меняется при запуске команды:

```
public RelayCommand StartCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _startCommand ?? (_startCommand = new RelayCommand(x =>
        {
            IsProcessing = true;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
            {
                _parseManager.DoWork(OutDbPath, WordDirPath, TempDirPath, Mode);
                IsProcessing = false;
            });
        }));
    }
}
```

И такой триггер в XAML:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProcessing}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProcessing}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Собственно, это работает, но не уверен, что нельзя сделать более лучше

Comment: привяжи команду к кнопке и определи метод CanExecute, тогда триггеры будут не нужны

Comment: @Gardes, Можно пример? А визуально дисейблить кнопку тоже можно будет без триггера?

Answer (score 0):

```
public RelayCommand StartCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_startCommand == null)
        {
            _startCommand = new RelayCommand(x => this.start(), x => this.IsProcessing);
        }
        return _startCommand;          
    }
}

void startExecute()
{
    IsProcessing = true;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
    {
        _parseManager.DoWork(OutDbPath, WordDirPath, TempDirPath, Mode);
        IsProcessing = false;
    });
}
```

---

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
        Content="Start"/>
```

Если команда будет не доступна(`IsProcessing == false`) то кнопка соответственно тоже будет не доступна

Comment: А реализацию CanExecute можно увидеть? А разве если передать enum тип в конструктор и изменять снаружи, то будут видны изменения внутри команды?

Comment: x => this.IsProcessing, вот здесь указывается, реализация CanExecute у вас уже есть, посмотрите в классе RelayCommand

Comment: У меня нету=\. Я сам делал реализацию. А RelayCommand-это какой-то паттерн?

Comment: У меня почему-то состояние кнопки не меняется...

Comment: @iluxa1810, IsProcessing свойство? Есть ли RaisePropertyChanged?

Comment: IsProcessing свойство. Попробовал вызвать _startCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); в обработчеке Start и вроде заработало.

Comment: Получается, что в свойстве я должен такой триггер повесить?      public bool IsProcessing
        {
            get => _isProcessing;
            set
            {
                _isProcessing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsProcessing));
                _startCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: @Gardes, ага, в вашем ответе нету вызова `CanExecuteChanged`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а RelayCommand- это какой-то паттерн? Что-то гугл молчит. Саму реализацию скопипастил с метанита, а потом нашел библиотеку MvvmLight, где она была в нескольких реализация.

Comment: @iluxa1810,  делайте так

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не всегда его нужно вызывать, он автоматически должен вызываться, бывают случаи конечно когда он не вызывается если действий с UI нет

Comment: @Gardes, это зависит от реализации `RelayCommand`, я предпочитаю реализацию, в которой он не вызывается на каждый чих :)

Comment: @iluxa1810, это реализация ICommand, она есть в каждом MVVM-фреймворке обязательно, но реализации могут отличаться. Я использую реализацию как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798617/218063) (`DelegateCommand`)

Comment: @Gardes, автоматически вызывается только при такой реализации: `public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; } remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; } }`, но не при простом `public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;`

Comment: @iluxa1810, вот что посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181248/6766879